# aggregating values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a deep dictionary like this:

```
myDict = { '123456': {
              '348adbd39r' : {
                    'LONDON': {
                          'c_name': 'abc',
                          'acct': '84720'
                          },
                    'PARIS': {
                          'c_name': 'xyz',
                          'acct': '73642'
                          }
                     },

              '2862aef3' : {
                    'NYC': {
                          'c_name': 'hhdls3',
                          'acct': '92742'
                          }
                     },

              '82gfg24' : {
                    'NYC': {
                          'c_name': 'hquer',
                          'acct': '34567'
                          },
                    'PARIS': {
                          'c_name': 'ljad',
                          'acct': '93742'
                          }
                     }
        }
```

I want to 'aggregate' it based on the city names. The output should look like below:

```
outDict = {
            'LONDON': {
                'c_name': ['abc'],
                'acct': ['84720']
             },
            'PARIS': {
                'c_name': ['xyz', 'ljad'],
                'acct': ['73642', '93742']
             },
            'NYC': {
                'c_name': ['hhdls3', 'hquer'],
                'acct': ['73642', '34567']
             }
         }
```

This is what I did:

```
cust_fields = ['c_name', 'acct']
field_dict = {field: [] for field in cust_fields}
aggregated_dict = {}

city_names = ['LONDON', 'PARIS', 'NYC']
for city in city_names:
   aggregated_dict[city] = field_dict


for id, an_dict in myDict.iteritems():
    for alphaNum, city_dict in an_dict.iteritems():
        for city, acct_dict in city_dict.iteritems():
            for field, val in acct_dict.iteritems():
                aggregated_dict[city][field].append(val)
```

But, the above is updating the field-values for all the cities...rather than just the particular city it is working on. Not sure where the logic is wrong. Any help is appreciated (either correct where my mistake is or any new logic...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is you are assigning `field_dict` to the value of `aggregated_dict[city]` in your loop over `city_names`, which is simply assigning the same dictionary to each city.  And when you update any reference (for any city) all references are updated.

An easy fix for this is to change

```
for city in city_names:
   aggregated_dict[city] = field_dict
```

To:

```
for city in city_names:
   aggregated_dict[city] = {field: [] for field in cust_fields}
```

I would also look at [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this type of aggregation.

```
from collections import defaultdict

collected = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for _, city_records in myDict['123456'].items():
    for city_name, records in city_records.items():
        for record_name, record_value in records.items():
            collected[city_name][record_name].append(record_value)


for city_name, records in collected.items():
    print city_name
    print dict(records)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,val in myDict.items():
    for key1,val1 in val.items():
        for key2,val2 in val1.items():
            d = final_dict[key2] if key2 in final_dict else defaultdict(list)
            for k,v in val2.items():
                d[k].append(v)
            final_dict[key2] = d
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
def aggregate(d):
   for a, b in d.items():
      if a in ['LONDON', 'PARIS', 'NYC']:
         global d1
         if a not in d1:

             d1[a] = {}

             d1[a]['c_name'] = [b['c_name']]
             d1[a]['acct'] = [b['acct']]
          else:
             d1[a]['c_name'].append([b['c_name']])
             d1[a]['acct'].append(b['acct'])
        else:
           aggregate(b)

aggregate(myDict)
print(dict(d1))
```

Output:

```
{'PARIS': {'acct': ['73642', '93742'], 'c_name': ['xyz', ['ljad']]}, 'NYC': {'acct': ['92742', '34567'], 'c_name': ['hhdls3', ['hquer']]}, 'LONDON': {'acct': ['84720'], 'c_name': ['abc']}}
```